# Google Map not displaying in fragment GoogleMap v2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on an application having an activity MapReminderActivity responsible for displaying map in a fragment id map but when the activity is rendered all I am getting is a blank fragment. and my Logcat states some authentication issues. I have checked the Api key even regenerated it and tried with that one but still getting blank fragment.

**MapReminderActivity:**

```
package com.afifagroup.gps;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import com.afifagroup.gps.R;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MapReminderActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener{
    private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
    GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mLocationClient;
    private Location mCurrentLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (servicesOK()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_reminder);

            if (initMap()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Map not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

    }
    private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng,
            float zoom) {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);
    }
    private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng) {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);
    }
    public void geoLocate(View v) throws IOException {
        hideSoftKeyboard(v);

        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String location = et.getText().toString();

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        Address add = list.get(0);
        String locality = add.getLocality();
        Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        double lat = add.getLatitude();
        double lng = add.getLongitude();

        gotoLocation(lat, lng, DEFAULT_ZOOM);

    }

    private void hideSoftKeyboard(View v) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    public boolean servicesOK(){
        int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            return true;
        }
        else if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)){
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to Google Play Services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean initMap() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag =
                    (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mMap = mapFrag.getMap();
        }
        return (mMap != null);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.d("Connection Falure Error",result.toString());

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        if(servicesOK()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.afifagroup.gps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" 
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" 
        android:maxSdkVersion="17"/>
 <permission
        android:name="com.afifagroup.gps.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.afifagroup.gps.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.afifagroup.gps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.afifagroup.gps.AllReminderActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_all_reminder" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.afifagroup.gps.CheckLocationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_check_location" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.afifagroup.gps.MapPointActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map_point" >
        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name="com.afifagroup.gps.MapReminderActivity"
            android:label="Select Place" >
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="*****API KEY****************" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Error Logs:**

```
E/dalvikvm(8541): Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
E/dalvikvm(8541): Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
E/dalvikvm(8541): [DVM] mmap return base = 469e3000
E/dalvikvm(8541): [DVM] mmap return base = 46f5d000
E/dalvikvm(8541): [DVM] mmap return base = 47b90000
```

Comment: Can you post your gradle build file?

Comment: @Faisal what version of google play services are you using ?if you are using 22nd version, try to get the map using the getMapAsync() method.

Comment: just make sure you registered the API key with the same package name as mentioned in your manifest

Comment: hi gautam I checked  my settings actually everything was fine just api was disabled

Comment: @FaisalNaseer how did you fixed this issue?? got same issue

Comment: @Maadhu there may be alot of issues relating to particular problem. you need to check the API is enabled from your developers console ans as Gautam said do check the api key also

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove below line from your manifest.xml file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.afifagroup.gps.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE" />
```

and check your layout.xml it should be like:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Comment: he is using SupportMapFragment.